# howto vba OpenText without parsing

Tags: excel, vba, file, parsing, text-files

I just want to get each line of text into the cell in the first column.
OpenText parses it, whatever I set the settings. Tried almost everything, (giving it DataType:=xlDelimited and Other:=True and OtherChar:="$" didn't help. Still parses the text and puts it in various cells of each row.

Using Open File #1 for input doesn't work for me because it won't read line by line, and puts the whole file into one string. (unix source).

What can I do.

---

Edited: As a side remark: I ended up using FSO correcting the Hebrew that I needed from each row with the following code:

```
Public Function CorrectHebrew(ByVal gibberish As String) As String


    Dim inStream As ADODB.stream

    Set inStream = New ADODB.stream
    inStream.Open
    inStream.Charset = "WIndows-1255"
    inStream.WriteText gibberish
    inStream.Position = 0
    inStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
    CorrectHebrew = inStream.ReadText
    inStream.Close

End Function
```

Comment: If it puts the whole file into a single string then you can get an array of lines from that using `Dim arrLines: arrLines = Split(theStringIGot, vbLf)`

Comment: Any particular reason for `OpenText`?

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu for asking. I was hoping it would read Hebrew (UTF8). It doesn't. (Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I have Local=true and tried it on a system where the windows locale is set to Hebrew...). If not Open Text, not FSO and not Open File for Input what else is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel remembers your settings for Text To Columns (which also apply to `OpenText`). If you don't explicitly set all of the arguments, then Excel will use the most recently used arguments.

Try providing values for all of the arguments (Macro Recorder *should* do that for you).

Comment: In the end I used FSO, and corrected the Hebrew line by line. I'll add the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Say we:

1. read the file one character at a time - into a really big string
2. replace any ASCII-13 with an ASCII-10
3. replace two sequential ASCII-10s with a single ASCII-10
4. parse and deposit the result

```
Sub OneCharacterAtATime()
    Dim s As String
    Close #1

    Open "C:\TestFolder\Inputs.txt" For Input As #1 Len = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        s = s & Input(1, #1)
    Loop
    Close #1

    s = Replace(s, Chr(13), Chr(10))
    s = Replace(s, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))

    ary = Split(s, Chr(10))

    i = 1
    For Each a In ary
        Cells(i, 1).Value = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

This should work with any type of line-break character combination.

Comment: Interesting answer (I gave you an upvote). for my side remark, but since I'm talking about a very large file, this is not the optimal way to go (filling up the memory). But thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @pashute  Give it a try..............in *VBA* a single string may be able to handle a **2G** text file.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem is the UTF8 (Hebrew Unicode) being read as gibberish.